# how to over ride php.ini

Tags: php

What are the ways available to over ride php.ini setting,

i want to over ride the max-life-time,

currently max life time is 30 min, i want to change this to 10 hrs,

Tell me the ways.

1. i  tried with ini_set in the php config page,
2. i tried with some log   ( with some snippets) ,
3. finally tried with .htaccess ,

But all of my above methods are failed,

Tell me some other ways to over ride the php.ini setting( max life time )

**For your information, i dont have the permission to access the php.ini file,**

Comment: Is the php.ini file in the root of your website? - if not, you should be able to override it by putting your own there.

Comment: Did you mean `max_execution_time`

Answer (score 3):

Which configuration directive are you referring to exactly?

The closest thing I can find is [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) which is settable via `ini_set()`, eg

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
```

You can change configuration settings based on the [change mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) of the directive and how PHP is run.

In general, any directive that is `PHP_INI_USER` or `PHP_INI_ALL` can be changed using `ini_set()`

If PHP is run as an Apache module, you can use the `php_value` and `php_flag` directives in an Apache configuration file (`httpd.conf`, `.htaccess`, etc)

If PHP is run via CGI (quite popular on shared hosts), you may be able to include your own `php.ini` file. There are certain subtleties to this method which I've blogged about extensively here - http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2009/08/php-suexec-and-custom-php-ini-files/

Comment: @user It should be `session.gc_maxlifetime`

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting the following into you `.htaccess` file

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Answer (score 0):

If ini_set isn't working, it's likely disabled in the server's php.ini file.  If this is the case, you likely can't override the setting, as preventing people from overriding settings is what disabling those functions is specifically for.  Even if you don't have access to change the php.ini file, do you have access to read it?  If so, look for a [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) setting.  If you don't have access to php.ini, try and see what this gives you:

```
echo ini_get('disable_functions');
```

Of course, that might have been disabled, too...

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting max-life-time, setting names do not contain dashes. Also max_life_time doesn't exist.

A [list of available settings](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) is available on the php website. Which setting are you trying to set/change?

Comment: i am trying maxlifetime, actual current problem is, assume system is idle around 30 min, after 31 min system automatically goes to logout when user hits some links, i want to change this system idle time to 10 hrs,

Comment: That setting is `session.gc_maxlifetime`, not just maxlifetime. You must use the correct name, or else you can't change the setting. The default value is 1440 seconds (24 minutes), you would need to set it to 36000 seconds (10 hours).

Comment: @user: see the answers given by Petah and Phil. Both options work. You can choose which one you prefer.